# getDatePicker() as a unresolved reference

Tags: android, kotlin, calendar, max, android-datepicker

I'm trying to set a max date to my calendar, and the following code that makes it work doesn't get along:

```
dpd.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
```

The `getDatePicker()` is seen as an unresolved reference.
I only saw this type of solution everywhere I checked.

What can I do?

Comment: could you paste your code to get more insight

Comment: Can you please share the code... else you can use BlackBoxDatePicker [https://github.com/BlackBoxVision/datetimepicker-edittext] as it's so easy to implement.